# Alternative of procman in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process

I want a program which gives all information relating to a currently running process. In Windows, there is [procman](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.prftools/doc/prftools/prftools09.htm) .

What's the alternative in LINUX?

Do I have to use tools like **strace**, etc. separately, or is there one program that does it all?

Do share if you know of a nice software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most tools that people will point you to will be just front ends to access all the information in `/proc`. If you want to know all the nitty-gritty about a process, check the files `/proc/<PID>`

Answer (score 1):

[GNOME System Monitor](http://packages.debian.org/sid/gnome-system-monitor) for system monitoring of a Linux Desktop (I run ubuntu 9.10)

It's simple and gives detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you know about them but top / iotop are pretty much the standard commands for process monitoring. Strace and Ltrace are also nice, but for more specific tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The most common and basic tool is "top". Open a terminal, run "top". Play with the options, see the inline help ( "h" key"). Benefit : works on any Linux/Unix/BSD box.

Answer (score -3):

I think you want the process monitor for Linux, right ?

you can easily detect via terminal

```
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.html
```

but if you do not prefer cmds , you can even use a ManageEngine® Applications Manager

```
http://www.manageengine.com/products/applications_manager/download.html
```

Cheers.